# How can you reproduce the same resultset with an optimal query automatically?

Tags: sql-server, automation

is it possible to make MSSQL Management Studio produce a query that will reproduce a resultset, that you found prior, but use the best way possible to recreate it?

Maybe there is a way to tell the database which rows it shall return instead of it looking for the correct rows by the WHERE conditions? So once you found the rows, you dont have to search again?

So what I thought is: When you place a condition like

```
Where col1 = 10
```

The DB will check row 1 col1 for value 10, then row 2 col1 and so on..
Like it is searching, which takes time. Whereas if you could just make a statement that just directly asks for the specific row, you are faster?

I mean you dont need to search for the columns either: You just say give me col1 or col2 or whatever

Comment: could you please explain your question in more details

Comment: Wouldn't that be great. A machine that turns any bad query into a great one automatically.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "the answer is just "no - this is not possible"

Comment: @MartinSmith, this is NOT a reason to close a question and leave it un-answered. A question which has yes/no answer is still legit question. If you think that this is the best answer, then provide it as answer. Some of the best questions are formulated in a short and direct way and their answers can be in one word.

Comment: In this case the question is not fully clear (at least to me) and I think more information and probably a screenshot can help a lot

Comment: @RonenAriely - the combination of the question asking for something highly localised and confused (SSMS will certainly not have functionality to reverse engineer a query from a resultset) and having no answer beyond "no" with no scope to elaborate further means it should just be closed and put out its misery

Comment: Good day @aludebe, Please try to elaborate a bit more and clarify what you mean. A screenshot might help a lot. Try to explain step but step what you expect to have. Be fast since in stackoverflow questions are closed fast for multipole reasons and we will not be able to help you if it will be if someone will close this thread.

Comment: Well... @MartinSmith... We should send the OP to Microsoft forums every time the question is going to be closed `:-)`. It is the perfect solution, as there the OP will be able to have a discussion and provide more information in steps and not only in the original question. In the Microsoft forums no one will close the question before the OP got everything he need. Once there will be final answer, then we can come here back to archive it in the SO. There should be 2 system which are connected: one for discussion forum and one for archive Q & A as stackoverflow. This could be perfect

Comment: ops... typo: `Try to explain step but step` means `Try to explain step by step` :-)

Comment: @RonenAriely You are welcome to put that on [meta] as an idea (I might even vote for it) but that is not how [so] works at the moment

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: NO

> is it possible to make MSSQL Management Studio produce a query that will reproduce a result set, that you found prior

SQL Server Management Studio does not store your queries or the result SET which the queries return. It is simply a client application which pass the queries to the database server and present the result which the server returns.

On the other hand, SQL Server do store all the queries which you execute (for some time, depend on multiple parameters). Using the following query you can get the last queries which were executed by the server:

```
SELECT execquery.last_execution_time AS [Date Time], execsql.text AS [Script] FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS execquery
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(execquery.sql_handle) AS execsql
ORDER BY execquery.last_execution_time DESC
GO
```

> ... use the best way possible to recreate it?

When you execute a query, then the server and the SSMS might provide some alerts and recommendation about the query, which can help us build a better query, but not the SQL Server and not the SQL Server Management Studio will build for you a better query based on a result SET of previous query

This is why we have DBA